# Nativescript onesignal push notification ios error

Tags: ios, push-notification, nativescript, onesignal

i've a nativescript (2.4.0) project with platform ios and android with this [plugin](https://github.com/roblav96/nativescript-onesignal) to use onesignal push notifications.

Android works perfectly but not Ios. When i try to build ios i receive these messages:

app/main.ts(9,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'UIResponder'.

app/main.ts(9,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'UIApplicationDelegate'.

app/main.ts(11,40): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'UIApplicationDelegate'.

app/main.ts(13,63): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'UIApplication'.

app/main.ts(13,93): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NSDictionary'.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Those are typescript warnings. You can bypass those a couple of different ways. I havent looked at the source of the plugin but you can declare those items so the ts compiler knows about them. Add the nativescript platform declarations, it's on npm from the NS team. Or to just get by for now set noEmitOnError = false in your tsconfig.json

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It works!! :)

Comment: For ios there are typings which is probably missing for you but you can add them to references :) Inside references.d.ts put this line 
`/// <reference path="./node_modules/nativescript-onesignal/typings/OneSignal.ios.d.ts" />`
*EDIT:* Together with ios typings or put them for example with UIResponder as `declare var UIResponder;`